# How do I keep windows XP from automatically changing the screen resolution?

Tags: windows-xp, graphics, tv, resolution

I have an Asus EEEBox (EB202, intel GMA 950) hooked up to my 1080p TV (DVI->HDMI cable).  I use it to watch standard definition movies and TV shows.

I prefer to run at 1280x720 so that I can see things more easily, but every time I turn off the TV, then back on again, the resolution defaults to 1080p (1920x1080).

How can I force a specific resolution? If that's not possible, is there a way to use a batch script to switch to the desired resolution faster?

Comment: Sounds video-card-specific.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you keep your TV display at its native 1080p setting.  This is the way to get the best display quality on LCD screens.

Instead of chaning the resolution, I would change the text size dpi settings, so that you can read text more easily, and set your media player software to scale video up so that it fills the screen.

Later versions of Windows make it easier to scale the text size larger, [but it is still possible in XP](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/display_use_large_or_small_fonts.mspx?mfr=true).

Comment: My only issue with that is that certain flash sites (hulu or youtube for example) run more smoothly when the display's screen resolution is 720p.  As it is now, 480p isn't perfectly smooth when the display's resolution is 720p, when it is 1080p there's a noticeable drop in performance.

Comment: @roamn: Does the CPU go to 100% when that stuttering happens? If it does, make sure that you have the latest graphics drivers and the latest version of Flash Player, because now Flash video can be hardware decoded by the graphics chip, and not by the CPU.